# How to set javascript value to jinja variable

Tags: javascript, jinja2

I know we can set Jinja variable  to js variable like this.

```
var x = {{ 'value' }}
```

but I am trying to do the reverse. i.e I am trying to set javascript value to jinja variable. I tried the following  but nothing worked.

```
{{value}} = x
{% set value = x %}
{% set value %} x {% endset %}
```

x is javascript variable.

is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 21):

This is not possible, and reflects a deep problem in your understanding of the web application architecture. jinja2 is a templating engine for Python, running on your server. JavaScript you are talking about is running in your browser.

When a server receives a request, it processes a jinja2 template to obtain the response it will send to the client. You cannot "set Jinja variable to js variable", you can render the page in such a way that eventually a JavaScript variable would be assigned a value that was in a Jinja2 variable. I.e. you start with `var x = {{ value }}` in jinja2 template; jinja2 transforms it into `var x = 42` during its rendering; then the rendered result gets sent to the client, which executes it as JavaScript, assigning a value 42 to `x`. The fact that there is a temporal sequence here (Python -> jinja2 -> rendered page source -> JavaScript) means you can't do what you want to do: The jinja2 variable and the JavaScript variable don't exist at the same time, nor in the same place, and assigning a JavaScript value to a jinja2 variable is impossible.

In order to send the value `42` to Python (and possibly later to jinja2), you would need to make a request that would send that value from client to server: a form submission, or an AJAX request.

You might get a better response if you would describe exactly what you want to do that you think requires you to "set javascript value to jinja variable".

Answer (score 5):

This is an old thread and the answer might still be "it cannot be done" but I would like to point out a mistake in both the answers above. The Question is "How to set javascript value to jinja variable". What He is asking is if you have JavaScript running on your front end page that needs a certain value to work and that value is given by the backend script and passed in via Jinja2 can you make that work? (AJAX perhaps).. Both "Answers" above while detailed and informative don't address this question. They both seem to address the opposite question, "Can you set a jinja2 variable from a javascript" which I agree does not make sense.
I'm looking for the answer to the same question (How to set javascript value to jinja variable) because [This tutorial](https://medium.com/python-in-plain-english/create-a-simple-covid-19-dashboard-with-flask-plotly-altair-chart-js-and-adminlte-a92ef86a3ca8) on flask with charts shows you inserting a jinja variable into a java script. The problem is Java looks at the double bracket ( {{ VAR1 }} )as part of the script and throws errors.

Answer (score 2):

The way you're describing, it can't be done.

Let's review Python, Jinja2, and JavaScript, because I think we can still achieve what you want.
Python is the language of your server, which will create the HTML sent to your clients.
Jinja2 is a templating engine for Python, which makes it easy to generate HTML without writing it directly.  Notice that you're calling a function like `render_template()` in your backend.  This generates the HTML using Jinja2 syntax, replacing Jinja2 statements with values known to the server, and inserting them into the HTML before it gets presented to the client.  Think of Jinja2 as shorthand for variable insertion and simple scripting for making HTML.
JavaScript is your frontend scripting language, running on the client's browser once the HTML has been generated and served.

The reason you can't use Javascript to "set a Jinja2 variable" is because there are no Jinja2 variables in the rendered HTML sent to the client.  Python and Jinja2 did that replacement on the server before sending the pure HTML/CSS/JS page to the client's browser.

Perhaps what you want to do though, is use frontend elements to change values that were initially set by python and Jinja2 on the backend.  To do this, you will need to have your JavaScript send information back to the server, so the server can use this information to rerender the page, possibly inserting new values into your templates using Jinja2 in the process.  Consider simply linking to a URL with the parameter you want to set.

You could link to `www.yourwebsite.com?x=value`, and now `x` will be set to `'value'` in the backend.  You can use this in your HTML template by including `{{ x }}`, which will resolve to 'value' when you call `render_template()`

Answer (score 1):

Well... you could send a post request from your javascript to the server and then from your python backend send the information to the html frontend

javascript frontend > POST > python backend > TEMPLATE > html frontend