# Python Jinja2 Assign javascript var from backend

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2

I'm having a for loop where i need to assign a python value to a javascript variable and i can't really make it work:(

```
{% for row in temp %}
    var year = {{ row[0]|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

I've tried in many ways but it will always give me

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
```

What's the right syntax for this?

Comment: i was looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383808/how-to-set-javascript-value-to-jinja-variable  and i thought that it's possible

Comment: Um.. I'm sorry I misread your question. Basically your code should be placed in a `<script></script>` block. And it is the same as injecting script into a html page. If you can show the whole file, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new line before the closing of the for loop is not inserted into the document, so the code running on the client side (e.g. for a loop of length 2) is this:

```
var year = '2018'var year = '2019'
```

If you try running this code, the exception you mentioned is raised. So this is a *client-side* error. The simplest solution is to add a **semicolon** at the end of the row, which allows multiple javacript declarations on the same row:

```
{% for row in temp %}
    var year = {{ row[0]|safe }};
{% endfor %}
```

Resulting in (for my example):

```
var year = '2018';var year = '2019'
```

I must say though, I do not understand the logic behind your code, as the variable 'year' gets overwritten upon each iteration.