# Set a python variable in flask with a button and javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask, jinja2, setter

I have a simple `Flask` app that contains a single variable called `variable`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

variable = 100

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/index/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', variable=variable)

def main():
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `index.html` file is as follows:

```
variable = {{ variable }}

<button onclick="setVariable(101);">
  set variable to 101
</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function setVariable(variable) {
    console.log(`variable = ${variable}`);
  }
</script>
```

**Is there any way to set the variable value within the `setVariable` function?** i.e. such that the value of `variable` is set to 101 in this example.

Basically the end goal is to dynamically set the value of `variable` using a button, which should furthermore update the `variable = {{ variable }}` line in the `index.html` file.

**EDIT**

The following implies you can not do this and must use an ajax request or something similar.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43383967/5058116

Comment: Do you need to send the variable back to the server and store it or do you just want it to increment client side?

Comment: @TomMillard Hey, yep back to the server, do some some stuff, then reload the index page. Not sure I want to change the URL though ... i.e. `/index/variable=101`. Perhaps just posting forms back using `url_for(index, form=some_form)` would be the way to go?

Comment: PS. `variable` could be (and is) an object ... just putting an `int` down for simplicity

Comment: Depends on whether or not you need it preserved on the server or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Use a form in `index.html` to post value to `@app.route('/index/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])` in `app.py`

Form in `index.html`

```
variable = {{ variable }}


<form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="101" name="variable">
    <input type="submit" value="set variable to 101">
</form>


{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
{% if messages %}
<ul>
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li style="color:red">{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

change `app.py` to process the form

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b'_1#y2l"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'

variable = 100


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    global variable
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            variable = int(request.form.get("variable"))
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        except:
            flash("Invalid type for variable")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('index.html', variable=variable)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

Adding `app.secret_key = b'_1#y2l"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'` to `flash` error message if user tries to send anything other than numbers

Comment: Cool -- seems sensible approach. What is `'index_cariable.html'`?

Comment: just a typo, fixed

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider to use `React` or `Vue`. Or please use database 
(`MySQL` or `MongoDB` etc) to store persistent data, and dynamically read the data with ajax.

And another solution, using websocket like [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) or nodejs may be nice.